# Paypal return url is giving blank array

Tags: paypal

```
  <form id="dvrr" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" align="center" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="business" value="ceo@world-airport-city-transfer.com">

      <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->

      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

      <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->

      <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Cab Booking">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $orderid; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo number_format((float)$data['price'], 2, '.', '');  ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

      <!-- Specify URLs -->

      <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.wer.com/payment-cancel/">
      <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.wer.com/payment-processing/">
      <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.wer.com/notify-payment/">

      <!-- Display the payment button. -->

      <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
      <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" ></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is my PayPal form that I'm using for payment, on thank you page we add the code to get the response and update it on our system that the transaction is complete or not.

we place this code on weburl.com/payment-processing/ that is our return URL

$data=$_POST;

```
        if($_POST['payment_status']!=''){
        $item_name=$_POST['item_name'];
        $item_number=$_POST['item_number'];
        $txn_id=$_POST['txn_id'];
        $payer_email=$_POST['payer_email'];
        $payment_gross=$_POST['payment_gross'];
        $payment_status=$_POST['payment_status']; 

        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO cr_payments(item_name,item_number,txn_id,payer_email,payment_gross,payment_status) VALUES('".$item_name."','".$item_number."','".$txn_id."','".$payer_email."','".$payment_gross."','".$payment_status."')") or die(mysql_error());
        global $wpdb;  
        $is_added = $wpdb->query("UPDATE cr_booking SET fld_booking_status = '$payment_status' WHERE fld_booking_id = '$item_number'");
```

but we get data when we run code on sandbox mode .. but on live mode we are getting blank array

Answer (score 0):

PayPal website payments standard, including the PayPal button you use, do NOT carry anything back to your return URL.

You will have to store data in your shopping cart before jumping to PayPal payment page.

Another PayPal product you can use, which is very different from the one you are using, is express checkout. It requires you to program the API calls between your server and PayPal, but the actual charge is done by calling doexoresscheckout on your server, so you can decide what to display according to the result of this API call.

Comment: And btw you can use IPN to get payment results, but IPN is asynchronous so it doesn't guarantee you get the results before buyers go back to your site. IPN should be used to automate your order processing.

Answer (score 0):

i resolve the issue by my custom way i just write the ipn data on a file by file_put_content and convert file data in to array and by twice exploding it by & and = i got the exact data after it on that bases we process the payment data in our website